# Using labels instead of anchor texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have been working on a widget and I'm pretty much done with the exception of a little thing that is bugging me a bit. The widget script that users will copy and paste on their website looks like this.

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/widget.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="my-chat" data-key="10"></a>
```

Then in the widget.js I have a line that adds an anchor text to the a tag like this.

```
$('.my-chat').html('Chat now');
```

I want the anchor text to be a certain color when active or on hover etc say blue and I have that described in its css file, however depending on the website it's placed on, their css may have other css properties for links and I realize that the anchor text of the widget gets modified depending on the website it's added on. I want to make the anchor text respect what I defined in the css of the widget, but I really don't know how. I saw this other widget that used labels, but I don't really understand what they are and how to use them.

Comment: Check out the `!important` modifier for CSS classes

Comment: you'll want to apply a mini-reset to a.my-chat. but, you have to consider that someone may WANT to style your like differently, and !important makes it harder to do that, so i would just use a very specific rule, and give the anchor and maybe a wrapper around it a certain ID for increased specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
 a.my-chat{ color:blue !important;}
    a.my-chat:hover{ color:red !important;}
```